# is there a faster way to display every index of an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im creating a function that will create a p element for every item in an array

```js
  const liArray = ["hello", "hi", "hello", "test", "hey"];

  const parentElement= document.getElementById("myDiv");
  const index1 = liArray.slice(-1);
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "1. " + index1;
  parentElement.appendChild(p);
  
  const index2 = liArray.slice(-2, -1);
  const p2 = document.createElement("p");
  p2.innerHTML =  "2. " + index2;
  parentElement.appendChild(p2);
  
  const index3 = liArray.slice(-3, -2);
  const p3 = document.createElement("p");
  p3.innerHTML =  "3. " + index3;
  parentElement.appendChild(p3);
   
  const index4 = liArray.slice(-4, -3);
  const p4 = document.createElement("p");
  p4.innerHTML =  "4. " + index4;
  parentElement.appendChild(p4);
 
  const index5 = liArray.slice(-5, -4);
  const p5 = document.createElement("p");
  p5.innerHTML =  "5. " + index5;
  parentElement.appendChild(p5);
```

so the result of this will be

```
1. hello
2. hi
3. hello
4. test
5. hey
```

and im wondering if there is any faster way to do it instead of manually slicing the array and creating elements like that which takes a lot of time especially if there is many items in the array

Comment: Loop over the items of the `liArray` and create the p element inside the loop. Then add it to the parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through each element of the array.

Try this

```js
const liArray = ["hello", "hi", "hello", "test", "hey"];

const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

liArray.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  var elm = document.createElement('p');
  elm.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${currentValue}`;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: hi i have another question here, what if i want to add a class to all the elements? how can i do so

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Loop over the array and append the newly created `p` element to the fragment.

When appending a series of elements to the DOM, DocumentFragment is preferred.

```js
const liArray = ["hello", "hi", "hello", "test", "hey"];

var fragment = new DocumentFragment()
const parentEl = document.getElementById("parent");

liArray.forEach(function(currentValue, index){
  var elm = document.createElement('p');
  elm.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${currentValue}`;
  fragment.appendChild(elm);
});

parentEl.appendChild(fragment)
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` for array.

see here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp